# How to view the intermediate layers of a keras model?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I want to visualize the intermediate layers of a keras model like this image.
[image]

I am  using the [CNN model](https://github.com/EN10/KerasMNIST/blob/master/cnn.py) in `github.com/EN10/KerasMNIST` which already has a pre-trained model. and the model look like this

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,199,882
Trainable params: 1,199,882
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I want to visualize the first,second convolution and dropout layers of this model and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46828989/996366) I simply have to do a forward pass to the layer which I want to visualize. The problem is the image is in the dimension of `28x28x1` whereas the first and second convolution layer dimension is `26x26x32` and `24x24x64` respectively and the dropout layer is `12x12x64`. How to convert these dimensios to image dimension so that we can get the images similar to the above one?